# The name of the model does not appear in the multiple choice field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a form with a multiple-choice field. I have a SchoolClass model and I want to select multiple classes in the form. I can select SchoolClasses in the form but it doesn't show anything as label. I don't know how to pass a name to the choice field.

Here is the form:

```
class ExamForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, class_choices, teacher_choices,teacher, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ExamForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['classes'].choices=SchoolClass.objects.filter(school_id=teacher.school_id)
```

I am getting SchoolClass objects for choices

```
classes = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(), widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
label = "Classes for this exam.")
```

When I run my project it shows like that :

[Blank choice fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjhdm.jpg)

Comment: The `choice`s expect a list of 2-tuples.

Comment: Can you share the details of your `classes` form field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `choices` expect an iterable of 2-tuples where the first item is the key, and the second one the rendered value.

You thus can implement this with:

```
def __init__(self, class_choices, teacher_choices,teacher, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ExamForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['classes'].choices = [
        (s.pk, str(s))
        for s in SchoolClass.objects.filter(school_id=teacher.school_id)
    ]
```

It might however be better to use a [**`ModelMultipleChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField), since then we can simply use the queryset, so something like:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    classes = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=SchoolClass.objects.none(),
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        label = 'Classes for this exam.'
    )

    def __init__(self, class_choices, teacher_choices,teacher, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['classes'].queryset = SchoolClass.objects.filter(school_id=teacher.school_id)
```

Comment: Both of the solutions are working, thank you so much. I guess ModelMultipleChiceField fits better for these kinds of fields right ?

Comment: @AhmetFarukYılmaz: yes, it removes a lot of boilerplate code, and you reduce the amount of logic *you* have to implement to parse the result.